# Photoshop Image Slicing For Web Design

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I have a webpage designed in Photoshop. But the primary background image is designed little different than the usual way.

[image: BAckground image]

[Large image](http://i48.tinypic.com/344zhuc.jpg).

I need to keep the texture and use the background in various pages where the height is dynamic. Any Ideas to simplify this ?

Comment: I fail to see any problem here. Maybe it's the coding that you need help with? Maybe you should elaborate a bit. (_What is the problem you're having?_)

Comment: Learn Cascading Style Sheets (CSS). It's fairly simply to make a dynamic background which will grow to match the height of content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to Cut 3 slice of this background 1 for header 2 for footer and 3 for center content and repeat this center background

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I have done. It took some time to cut the center part since the border is not straight.

Comment: you have to slice like 2% first 2% third and 96% center and background repeat x repeat and adjust you center part with last hope this will work..